# Redirect Users From Old URL To New

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Each user can visit their account profile by www.example.com/profile/{username}

note: username contains numbers and letters only

For example:
www.example.com/profile/michaelwatson
www.example.com/profile/jenniferlee2

Would like to redirect from old URL:
www.example.com/profile/jenniferlee2

to the new shorter URL 
www.example.com/jenniferlee2

I want anyone that have old bookmarks to go from old URL to the new URL and anyone looking but only for profile URLs. Anything else should remain the same.

This is what I tried adding to .htaccess but getting internal server error

RewriteRule (.*) /profile/$1 [L]

Comment: And how do you know a profile is not a profile with the new URL from the OLD one? For instance if I access `http://www.example.com/contact` and that is handled by index.php I will get redirected to `/profile/contact` given your current rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile/(\w+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profile/
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /profile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it breaks other links (adds /profile to other links). If I click on http://www.example.com/account/lostpass it says The requested URL /profile/account/lostpass was not found on this server.

Comment: BUt you didn't provide any mechanism when to put `/profile` and when no to? Can you clarify?

Comment: Can you please explain what mechanism you are referring to so I can provide the right information?

Comment: I want to know what URI patterns should be rewritten to `/profile`?

Comment: I've edited my first post to make it clearer. This is the format is shows for each person: http://www.example.com/profile/username